# Check Dataframe by Row, over multiple columns and Code 1 for positive and 0 for negative

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a set of columns, all coded as factors. The values are coded as 1 for positive and 0 for negative. Samples on rows, and scores for each on the columns.

I want to find out, sample wise, if there are any positives. If there is at least one positive, I want to generate a new column in the same database which says 1, as in this sample was positive for at least one, or 0 as in this sample was negative for all.

```
    dat3 <- structure(list(A = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"),
                   B = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
                   C = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("nd","0", "1"), class = "factor"),
                   D = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
                   E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0","1"), class = "factor")),
                  .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 24L))
```

I tried and achieved the result I wanted by using if and if else statements, but they are really tedious and I don't think thats the best way to do it. I've been trying the apply function, but I haven't had much success.

The result I'm expecting is

```
dat3$result <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that you want to achieve given this example input?

Comment: I've just Edited the question to include the result. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanThompson Hi, the result I'm expecting is dat3$result <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'dat3' columns are all `factor`, which can be converted to `numeric` then use `rowSums` to create a binary column

```
dat3$result <- as.integer(rowSums(sapply(dat3, function(x) 
                     as.integer(as.character(x))), na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

---

Or convert to a logical matrix and then do the `rowSums`

```
as.integer(rowSums(dat3 == "1")> 0)
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me as even when there is a positive in the dataset, the result comes out as negative.

Comment: @Ar1229  It is based on your example and it is giving the expected output

Comment: @Ar1229  Even after you edits, the expected output is the same.  so, I don't know how you negative

Comment: No it isn't. I'm sorry if the output or the question wasn't clear. I basically want to loop over a number of columns and generate a new column called results. Even if one of the columns I loop over is 1, I want the result to be 1 not 0. The result can take two values, 1 or 0.

Comment: @Ar1229  Isn't that I showed there, the output is 1 or 0. `0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1`  `rowSums` is exactly doing the same thing by taking the sum of a logical matrix and check if there is any 1 in each row\

Comment: there are instances where there are 1 positives for a sample and your code still gives me a 0. I can put the entire data here, and after the fifth row, it gives me 0,1,0,1 etc. Thank you for taking the time to look through it and giving me an answer though

Comment: Hi Akrun, Sorry about all the confusion. The error I was getting was because of another piece of code early on in the script. Your solution is pristine. Thanks again!